# Finding sum of ACF custom field value for comments

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a few custom fields for comments to allow reviews on a Wordpress site built for listing hotels with user reviews as comments. One of these custom fields is a 'star_rating' field. I need to find a way to fetch the total sum of all values in order to find the average 'star_rating' value for each post to be displayed in search results and on the listing profile.

I have been trying for a long time to find the total sum for the star_rating field values. I have last used the following code but it does not work although I cannot see why. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$ratings_sum = 0;
// Arguments for the query
$args = array();
// The comment query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
// The comment loop
if ( !empty( $comments ) ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        $ratings_sum+= $comment->star_rating;
    }
} else {
    // echo 'No comments found.';
}
echo $ratings_sum;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: custom field 'star_rating' saved in post meta or comment meta table for each post?

Comment: @AshPatel 'star_rating' is saved in the comment meta table

Comment: did you try `get_field` acf method? `get_field('star_rating', $comment)`. Also can you add echo in foreach cycle to see what values do you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ACF custom field plugin, try to use [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function. You can't access your custom field `$comment->star_rating` like this.

Comment: Many thanks - this fixed the problem exactly as I needed it to

Answer (score 0):

Try below custom query for fetch star rating:

```
SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE comment_id IN (SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID = '//your post id') and meta_key='star_rating';
```

Comment: Hi @AshPatel - I have altered the code as you suggested as follows but $ratings_sum now returns a value of 1 for all posts (rather than remaining at 0 as before). Could there be another reason why the total star_ratings is not being counted? Thanks

Comment: yes there may be another reason..please check what is exactly rating for post in which query is returning 1.